# Closing the Main JFrame

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, jframe

I have a main jFrame with the help of which i press button and open new JFrames but the problem is that when i open other JFrame the previous ones still remains there where as what i want is that when i press next button then i move forward to the new JFrame (the previous one should not be there) and when i press previous button i move back to the previous JFrame.

I know there are functions of dispose,they do well like jframe1.dispose() but i dont get it how to hide the very first JFrame whose code in the main is written like this

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {


    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() 
          {          
           new GraphicalInterface().setVisible(true);
          }
       });
     }
```

how do i set this as .setVisible(false) in the button code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to retain a reference to the `JFrame`, so you can set it's visibility later.

```
private JFrame myFrame;

public void run() {
  myFrame = new GUI();
  myFrame.setVisible(true);
}

public void hide() {
  myFrame.setVisible(false);
}
```

Note that a `JFrame` is a top-level container, you are only really supposed to have one per application. It may be better if instead of using multiple `JFrame`s you use just one, and swap in various `JPanel`s instead.

Comment: Note that the native screen resources won't be released if you just call `setVisible(false)`. If you don't plan to reuse the window, use the `dispose()` method instead.

Answer (score 0):

It would safe resources if you keep just one frame and set a new panel as content.

Your question was how to handle the reference to the frame? Please provide the code where the next frame is created.

Answer (score 0):

You could assign your GUI (extends JFrame I suppose) to a variable and call .setVisible(false) on that object. Since your object from the code above is more or less anonymous, you won't have access on that.

You could also check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation%28int%29).